# Access Current Configurable Products Configurations

Tags: magento, magento2

I am looking to create an array on my Magneto 2 product page that contains the current configurable products configurations. Say I have the options Finish, Size, and Top. Is there an API that can give me the product currently selected? Ideally I would like to have the admin values for each configuration as well so I could pass it around the website.

I have tried accessing the data from the front end but some of it doesn't appear like the admin values and for what does appear is is a clunky solution to crab the values by targeting the class name and accessing the values that way

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of Magento 2 API endpoints [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/list.html) which includes one for getting the list of configurations.

GET    /V1/configurable-products/:sku/options/all

The next step is to access it where you need it.